# Hazelcast: Will item added listener gets triggered across all nodes when I add and clear ISet in the same function?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to trigger item added listener trigger across all nodes when I add items, make an async call in the listener, and after the listener is triggered I want to clear the ISet.

According to the EntryProcessor logic, each query is executed as an entry processor and I'm presuming it coherently triggers the item added listener across all nodes. My initial tests also point to the same behavior. But since I'm dealing with production data, I want to be 100% sure that item added listener gets triggered in all the nodes, even though I'm clearing the ISet in the next moment in one of the nodes.

Kindly point me to documentation if you know any. Or please share your experiences if you faced similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the requirement "I want to be 100% sure that item added listener gets triggered in all the nodes", I'd suggest ReliableTopic and also make sure your topic listener implementations use `ReliableMessageListener` interface, as you can see it has additional interfaces for storing (storeSequence();) and getting sequence number (retrieveInitialSequence();), for example you can store this info locally on client. So each client will listen to the events based on the sequence id, which means if it disconnects for some reason, it can resume from the latest event sequence id after it restores.
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Reliable_Topic.html

Comment: Thanks @sertug. Let me try implementing it.

Comment: ITopic may not serve my purpose, I do not want any sequence or store the sequence as I'm only using it to build cache. If one of the boxes goes down, We will simply reload the cache again.

Comment: storing sequence is required in order not to lose/miss any listener events in case of a disruption.

Comment: Can you please tell me about the kind of disruptions possible here. Thanks.

Comment: Listener can go offline for some time and can not receive the events during that time, when it comes back online,  you might want to continue listening from the last message you left. Also please see: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.8.1/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/topic/ReliableMessageListener.java